# How to compare two dates with only month and year in mule

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

My scenario is to check if the Month and year (in date value) is less than the current month and year (in current date value).

The condition I need to implement is this

```
if source-month&year  < current-month&year Yes else No
```

Scenario 1:current date = 03/29/2024 (MM/dd/yyyy) and source incoming date = 03/01/2021 (MM/dd/yyyy). In this case it should give me Yes

Scenario 2: current date = 03/29/2024 (MM/dd/yyyy) and source incoming date = 03/01/2024 (MM/dd/yyyy). In this case it should give me No.

I tried using .month and .year but it always giving result as No

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it is working as you expected .upvote if it is working

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var currentDate = now()
var currentYear = currentDate.year
var currentMonth = currentDate.month
var inputDate = "03/01/2024" as String {format: "MM/dd/yyyy"}
var inputYear = (inputDate as Date {format: "MM/dd/yyyy"}).year
var inputMonth = (inputDate as Date {format: "MM/dd/yyyy"}).month

---
if (inputYear < currentYear or (inputYear == currentYear and inputMonth < currentMonth)) 
    "Yes"
else 
    "No"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably turn both of the dates into the first of the month and then compare.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var a = |2024-03-23T02:47:40.014782Z|
var b = |2024-03-30T02:48:34.216274Z|

fun firstOfMonth(d) = 
    d as String {format: "yyyy-MM-01"} as Date
---
{
    a: a,
    b: b,
    less: firstOfMonth(a) < firstOfMonth(b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below snippets. It will work as per your requirement.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var inpDate = "03/01/2024" as Date {format:"MM/dd/yyyy"}
var today = now() as Date {format:"MM/dd/yyyy"}
---

{
    "inpDate": inpDate,
     today:today,
    "isCheck":  (inpDate.month + inpDate.year) < 
(today.month + today.year)
}
```